# Access Denied to amazon AWS SQS through CLI or API

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am getting access denied when I try to access the Amazon SQS through CLI or API. This is the node.js code:

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});

var credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
AWS.config.credentials = credentials;

// Create the SQS service object
var sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: 'latest'});

var params = {
  MaxResults: 10
};

sqs.listQueues(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", data);
  }
});
```

The sqs policy is the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "__owner_statement",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::437568002678:root",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:role/MyRole",
          "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNTID:user/username"
        ]
      },
      "Action": [
        "sqs:GetQueueAttributes",
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "sqs:ListQueues"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-1:ACCOUNTID:NAME"
    }
  ]
}
```

The complete error is:

```
Error AccessDenied: Access to the resource https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ is denied.
```

The credentials file is set at `/home/user/.aws/credentials`.

I am using one account for AWS services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reproduce your situation I did the following:

- Created an **IAM User** with no permissions
- Configured the AWS CLI to use credentials associated with the new IAM User
- Created a standard (non-FIFO) **Amazon SQS queue**
- **Attached your policy** to the queue, but with an updated `Resource` and `Principal`
- Used the AWS CLI to **send a message** to the SQS queue:

```
aws sqs send-message --queue-url https://sqs.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/123456789012/queuename --message-body foo
```

The message was **successfully sent to the queue**. This means that the Access Policy on the SQS queue was sufficient to grant permission to send the message, without requiring any additional permissions on the IAM User.

Therefore, either your AWS CLI is *not* using the IAM User referenced in your Access Policy or there are some permissions on the IAM User or Account SCP that is specifically denying the ability to use `SendMessage()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have not tried but I can send message too, do you know how to read messages?

Comment: You said that you are "getting access denied when I try to access the Amazon SQS through CLI or API", but now you have said that you can send a message. Can you also use `aws sqs list-queues`? If that works through the AWS CLI but not in your code, it suggests that your code is not using the same credentials.

Comment: Yes sorry, I tried with ListQueues only and it didn't worked before and now, so I thought it was a general access problem, I haven't tried with sendMessage before but it worked.

Comment: I am confused. Can you please clarify what is working and what is _not_ working? Feel free to Edit your question with updated information.

Comment: Don't worry I accept the answer, because I know how it works.